# Im trying to add a map to my app but all I see is a black screen.....Why?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit

Im trying to make a map show up and give the users location in the map but all I get is a black screen. I feel like I set it up correctly but its not working for me. Does anyone see something in my code that is not right or something I forgot to add? Heres the code:

```
class MapScene: SKScene, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

var locationMangaer = CLLocationManager()
var map : MKMapView! = MKMapView()


override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    locationMangaer.delegate = self
    locationMangaer.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationMangaer.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationMangaer.startUpdatingLocation()
    locationMangaer.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

    map.showsUserLocation = true
    map.delegate = self
    map.showsBuildings = true
    map.showsPointsOfInterest = true
    map.zoomEnabled = true
    map.scrollEnabled = true
    map.zoomEnabled = true
    map.rotateEnabled = true
    map.mapType = MKMapType.Hybrid
    map.pitchEnabled = false
    map.userInteractionEnabled = true


}



//DELEGATE METHODS

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
    println(error)
}

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {


    var userLocation: CLLocation = locations[0] as! CLLocation
    locationMangaer.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(userLocation.coordinate.latitude, userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.05, 0.05)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location, span: span)

    self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    println("call")
}
```

Comment: Check that the `MKMapView` is added to superview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work....I had to add these two lines of code:

```
    map.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, frame.size.width, frame.size.height - 50)
    self.view?.addSubview(map)
```